# What is the difference between the criteria argument and the k= argument in step() in R?

Tags: r, stepwise-regression

What exactly is difference between the 'criteria' argument for the step() function in r thats described in the documentation here: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/emdi/html/step.html

versus the 'k = ' argument described here:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/step

I tried running two models, one uses the criteria argument set to "BIC" and the other uses k = log(n). The two produce very different results.

Comment: These are two different functions from two different packages, and the two parameters have very different semantics. Have you looked at the documentation you link to? What exactly is unclear?

Comment: Hi Stephan, I thought they referred to the same function which makes sense now as I was confused why one had different arguments than the other. I guess what I don't understand is, why they produce very different results when I understood k = log(n) to be "BIC" from the documentation.

Comment: OK, thanks, I see your point. `emdi::step(..., criteria="BIC")` and `stats::step(...,k=log(n))`, where `n` is the number of data points, should in principle yield the same result, and for you, they don't. Can you edit your post to include a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/452096)? If I just create a random example, both unsurprisingly yield the same end result.